# HOWTO: Convert Task<MyBoolResult> into MyBoolResult class object

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, async-await, asp.net-web-api2

I have an ASP.NET MVC application which is caling to a WEB API REST service method.

I am using a custom MyBoolResult object to return if operation has been successful or not. This is a class with some constructors and properties.

Now I am trying to convert Task into a MyBoolResult in DoWork method. How can I achieve this?

Below the code snippet:

```
public MyBoolResult DoWork()
{
        string requestUri = "api/MyController/CreateFile";
        CustomObject myParams = new CustomObject();

        // Below line does not work. How can I convert the returned object into MyBoolResult?
        MyBoolResult myBoolObject = this.CreateFile(requestUri, myParams);

        return myBoolObject;
}

public async Task<MyBoolResult> CreateFile(string requestUri)
{
     // Here some stuff and initializations
     // To simplify I am not putting here all the code previous to PostAsync

     HttpResponseMessage res = await client.PostAsync(requestUri, httpContent);
     if (res.IsSuccessStatusCode)
     {
         var webApiResp = res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
         result = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyBoolResult>(webApiResp);
     }
     else
     {
         result = MyBoolResult.ToErrorResult(String.Format("An error occurred! HTTP error code {0}", res.StatusCode));
     }

     return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DoWork will need to be async as well.  Otherwise the execution will skip over that code.  Async is a bit contagious that way.

```
public async Task<MyBoolResult> DoWork()
{
    string requestUri = "api/MyController/CreateFile";
    CustomObject myParams = new CustomObject();

    // Below line does not work. How can I convert the returned object into 
    MyBoolResult?
    MyBoolResult myBoolObject = await this.CreateFile(requestUri, myParams);

    return myBoolObject;
}
```

`Task` does have a result property, but you would need to call [`Task.Wait()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.wait?view=net-5.0) which will lock the calling thread and defeat the purpose of using async.

Comment: but then the method who calls DoWork needs to be async as well. And from that method if I try to do this: MyBoolResult res = DoWork(); then I get the error: cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<MyBoolResult>' to 'MyBoolResult'

Comment: Yes, async has a tendency to become contagious.  At the top level there is usually a button call or something that has initiated the work.  This top level shouldn't depend on the results of an async method, just initiate it and move on.  Or you will have a method stub `async void SomeCall().`  If your whole process depends on the result of the work and can't do anything else until it's done, then I would consider not using async.

Comment: Yes, I see, this is contagious, all the method calls in the chain must be async-await in order to make the code "synchronous", I mean, to wait for the called method to finish and complete. And Yes, I have a button call at the top level. When button is pressed in my asp.net mvc view, from javascript, I make an asynchronous call using jquery  $.ajax(....). This calls an action in the controller so I understand I must mark this first action method as async and inside this put an await and so on for the rest of the calls until to reach the last method where web api REST is invoked. Am I right?

Comment: @Ralph Yes, your controller action needs to be async too. Also all async methods need to return a task (never do `async void`), and you should neither call Wait() nor Result on a task.

Answer (score 1):

```
MyBoolResult myBoolObject = await this.CreateFile(requestUri, myParams);
```

DoWork will need to be changed to async.  Alternatively you can use .Result on the createfile call, but I don't recommend this for potential deadlocking issues.